# Perl - segmentation fault when attempting to sort a hash object

Tags: perl, hashmap

Dear StackOverflow community,

Hello, I am trying to execute some code developed by a third party (https://sourceforge.net/projects/apatrap/files/), and I am running into a few difficulties I am afraid.

I have a large hash object in which each value in the list is an array. The hash object looks like this (with only 3 items in the list printed for the sake of brevity):

```
{
           'ENSMUST00000078497|NA|7|+' => [
                                           '7',
                                           142515776,
                                           142516008,
                                           142515776,
                                           142516008,
                                           '+'
                                         ],
          'ENSMUST00000098266|NA|7|+' => [
                                           '7',
                                           99601098,
                                           99616771,
                                           99601098,
                                           99606771,
                                           '+'
                                         ],
          'ENSMUST00000206370|NA|7|-' => [
                                           '7',
                                           3620974,
                                           3620983,
                                           3620974,
                                           3620983,
                                           '-'
                                         ]
};
```

The hash object is called `%utr_events_dict`.

Next, we try to sort this hash object and assign this to a new variable using the following code:

```
my @sorted_utr_events = sort { @{$utr_events_dict{$a}}[0] cmp @{$utr_events_dict{$b}}[0] or
                        @{$utr_events_dict{$a}}[1] <=> @{$utr_events_dict{$b}}[1] } keys %utr_events_dict;
```

This line specifically causes a segmentation fault. In the past, I have been able to execute this script without issue (albeit in a different computing environment). I don't think this is a problem of limited memory, as I have tried running this job with excess memory (~ 200GB), but I still get the segementation fault.

I am not proficient in reading perl, but as far as I am aware the above line for sorting the hash object is valid code, and therefore I do not understand why I am seeing the segmentation fault here.

Any help is appreciated

Here is some information about my environment:

**Perl:** 5.26.2
**OS:** linux; 4.4.0-96-generic
**compiler:** gcc (4.8.2)

**EDIT:**

To help debug the code, I created a new script, manually declared the very short hash object which I have written above, and then applied the same sort function as I have written above. This much shorter script ran without any problem.

I am also using a much simpler syntax for the sort function:

```
my @sorted_utr_events = sort {
$utr_events_dict{$a}[1] <=> $utr_events_dict{$b}[1] 
} keys %utr_events_dict;
```

But this simpler version of the function still fails in the main script.

So I imagine this must be some kind of run-time error, and a problem with how the main script is allocating memory perhaps?

e.g. maybe the call to **sort** triggers use of buffer memory which was somehow filled by an upstream process? I don't know - I don't have a good low-level understanding of how memory works. The hash object itself I am sorting is very small, so I cannot imagine that this is using up too much memory

**EDIT2:** The sort function is called without error if the hash object only contains one key-value pair

**EDIT3:** Specific debug info using `gdb perl` with the `bt` command:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555639a3f in S_sv_unmagicext_flags.part.14 ()
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-307.el7.1.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000555555639a3f in S_sv_unmagicext_flags.part.14 ()
#1  0x0000555555639bee in Perl_sv_unmagic ()
#2  0x0000555555638b66 in Perl_sv_clear ()
#3  0x00005555556394c1 in Perl_sv_free2 ()
#4  0x000055555566b683 in Perl_leave_scope ()
#5  0x00005555556d1c80 in Perl_pp_sort ()
#6  0x000055555562b5b6 in Perl_runops_standard ()
#7  0x00005555555ac3c7 in perl_run ()
#8  0x0000555555583ad2 in main ()
```

Also, here is the output from `valgrind`:

```
==15994== Invalid read of size 1
==15994==    at 0x4CF154: S_sv_unmagicext_flags.part.12
==15994==    by 0x4CF2DD: Perl_sv_unmagic
==15994==    by 0x4CE255: Perl_sv_clear
==15994==    by 0x4CEB8C: Perl_sv_free2
==15994==    by 0x4FE6CC: Perl_leave_scope
==15994==    by 0x561D97: Perl_pp_sort
==15994==    by 0x4C1675: Perl_runops_standard
==15994==    by 0x444F0F: perl_run
==15994==    by 0x41D8CA: main
==15994==  Address 0xff00000012 is not stack\'d, malloc\'d or (recently) free\'d
==15994==
==15994==
==15994== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==15994==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xFF00000012
==15994==    at 0x4CF154: S_sv_unmagicext_flags.part.12
==15994==    by 0x4CF2DD: Perl_sv_unmagic
==15994==    by 0x4CE255: Perl_sv_clear
==15994==    by 0x4CEB8C: Perl_sv_free2
==15994==    by 0x4FE6CC: Perl_leave_scope
==15994==    by 0x561D97: Perl_pp_sort
==15994==    by 0x4C1675: Perl_runops_standard
==15994==    by 0x444F0F: perl_run
==15994==    by 0x41D8CA: main
==15994==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==15994==  overflow in your program\'s main thread (unlikely but
==15994==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==15994==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==15994==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==15994==
==15994== HEAP SUMMARY:
==15994==     in use at exit: 30,097,366 bytes in 50,442 blocks
==15994==   total heap usage: 688,990 allocs, 638,548 frees, 64,836,237 bytes allocated
==15994==
==15994== LEAK SUMMARY:
==15994==    definitely lost: 1,871 bytes in 24 blocks
==15994==    indirectly lost: 3,811 bytes in 44 blocks
==15994==      possibly lost: 11,591,244 bytes in 21,076 blocks
==15994==    still reachable: 18,500,440 bytes in 29,298 blocks
==15994==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==15994==                         newarray           : 93,632 bytes in 2,920 blocks
==15994==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15994== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==15994==
==15994== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==15994==
==15994== 1 errors in context 1 of 1:
==15994== Invalid read of size 1
==15994==    at 0x4CF154: S_sv_unmagicext_flags.part.12
==15994==    by 0x4CF2DD: Perl_sv_unmagic
==15994==    by 0x4CE255: Perl_sv_clear
==15994==    by 0x4CEB8C: Perl_sv_free2
==15994==    by 0x4FE6CC: Perl_leave_scope
==15994==    by 0x561D97: Perl_pp_sort
==15994==    by 0x4C1675: Perl_runops_standard
==15994==    by 0x444F0F: perl_run
==15994==    by 0x41D8CA: main
==15994==  Address 0xff00000012 is not stack\'d, malloc\'d or (recently) free\'d
==15994==
==15994== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: What values are returned by `perl -V:'archname|ptrsize'`?

Comment: `@{$utr_events_dict{$a}}[0]` is taking an array slice, which is subtly incorrect. `@{$utr_events_dict{$a}}[0]` is taking an array element, which is more correct. But it's more simply written as  `$utr_events_dict{$a}->[0]`. I don't think that's the problem, but give it a shot. And it's much easier to read.

Comment: Or just `$utr_events_dict{$a}[0]`. But yeah, not the issue.

Comment: @Schwern - thanks, the code is easier to read now, although it hasn't fixed the segfault I am afraid

@ikegami: Thanks - the output is:

`archname='x86_64-linux-thread-multi';`
`ptrsize='8';`

Comment: Having extra memory is useless if you're using a 32-bit program, but you're not. Well, needless to say, it's not suppose to crash, and going further will require a debugger (e.g. running `perl` via `gdb` and using the `bt` command to obtain a stack backtrace). But first, you should try using the latest version of Perl (5.32), not one that's three versions and three years behind. Maybe use `perlbrew` to install the latest in your home dir?

Comment: It looks like an ENSEMBL (or another biological database) flat file that was read into a hash. Perhaps during parsing some hash elements happen to have less than 2 elements in the anonymous array. This will fail to sort because the element with index 1 does not exist. Not sure whether it will segfault, though.

Comment: As a workaround, can you dump the hash into a file in tab-delimited format suitable for sorting as you need it, sort the file using *NIX `sort` with multiple keys, then read it back into the `@sorted_utr_events`?

Comment: (My previous made 5.26 sound a bit old. It's not really, but it's still three versions behind, so it's possible this is a problem that has already been fixed. So it's worth trying the latest.)

Comment: Roughly how many keys does %utr_events_dict have? You may be hitting some 32-bit limits. Before 5.20.0, arrays were limited to **31 entries, and there may some residual limits you're now hitting.

Comment: Not claiming it will work, but you could try to sort by a Schwartzian transform. Which, if it works, also might sort faster than your approach would. Like this: `my @sorted_utr_events = map $$_[1],
        sort {$$a[0] cmp $$b[0]}
        map [sprintf("%30s %15d",@{$utr_events_dict{$_}}[0,1]), $_],
        keys %utr_events_dict;`

Comment: Does your program work with short hash? Like with example 3 keys above?

Comment: Apologies for the delay in getting back to everyone - I have been very busy today. To answer Dave Mitchell, the number of keys for the hash object is 11495.

However, I tried running the script by subsetting the hash object to only 2 keys, as suggested by @w.k and still encountered a seg fault. I ran this through a debugger, and I see many, many calls to different subroutines of the carp module. The final subroutine called before the seg fault is a call to Carp::ret_backtrace 'return $mess;'

Comment: Well if it only requires two keys, the next thing to do it to reduce the code to the bare minimum which reproduces the fault and post it here. As far as possible, eliminate any dependency on external files or modules. It's possible that during this process of simplification you may stumble upon the critical part of the code.

Comment: I should also mention @ikegami that I am installing perl with `conda` - which limits the version of perl I can use. perl is a dependency for a tool that I am working on, and ideally I would like users to install it without needing root access, hence the use of `conda`